# How to integrate OpenAPI into Azure API Management using Azure DevOps CI & CD pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, openapi, azure-api-management

I have created an Azure API Management instance. I want to integrate OpenAPI into Azure API Management using Azure DevOps CI & CD pipelines.

For each release, I want to generate the OpenAPI spec from the code automatically. How can I build on this OpenApi spec to set up Azure API Management with all required version sets, apis, products, tags, users, subscriptions, certificates, and policies?

Comment: You can refer to [CI/CD for API Management using Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates) and [Build a CI/CD pipeline for API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/build-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-api-management/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Sample Document where you can Automate Open API to APIM using CI/CD pipelines

> https://www.domstamand.com/automating-your-openapi-updates-to-api-management-through-your-cicd-pipeline/

we need to use the [Swashbuckle CLI](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli) which can be use to retrieve the Swagger/OpenAPI JSON directly from the application’s startup assembly, and write it to a file. Follow the [configuration](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcorecli) to add the CLI to your source control repository so you can restore the tool and use it in your CI build definition.

Comment: Hey @Pradeep, has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: If the posted answer justifies your requirement, you may [mark it as the answer] by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Doing so can benefit other community members

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use the Swashbuckle CLI to generate the OpenApi spec file.

You can use this devops extension to easily configure your API Management API's through your CICD pipeline: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim