# Create an HTTP API by using Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to Create An Http Api Using Azure Pipelines

I have a Flask Api that is deployed to a Aks Pod exposed through a privat LB
with api management in the same vnet

Here Is What I'm Trying to Achieve :

[image: Aks With APIM]

oing it it manually Works Fine with the pod private ip adresse :

Note : Im using http api not openAPI

[image]

[image]

- when i configure the api from Azure Devops Pipeline

[image]

- API Management - Create/Update Product : succeed
- API Management - Create/Update API : Failed

[image]

[image]

**i understand that it's an openapi configuration in the pipelines but i couldn't find any pipeline to cnofigure http api in devops**

Comment: well, the most important information is under the red color. The 'link' is not valid.

Comment: this is the link **https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/*******/resourceGroups/*******/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/api-mlops/apis/aks-test?api-version=2021-10-01**

Comment: Hey @Mohammed have you gne through this SO thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71885383/how-to-integrate-openapi-into-azure-api-management-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-pi

Comment: Hey @SaiSakethGuduru-MT this link is for  OpenAPI not Http api  I'm trying to create Http Api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Solved this problem by using Terraform files

Following [this Procedure](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2019/10/08/using-a-api-management-in-front-of-an-azure-kubernetes-cluster/)

We Adapted The Terraform Files To our Pipelines :

We First Created The API then The Operations as you can see in the pipeline :

[image]

And Then added the init,plan and apply tasks on the stage :

[image]

And Just like That We created and configured the Api
[image]